# Passing Multiple url parameters breaks page link

Tags: php, url, url-parameters

I have a weird issue where passing multiple parameters to a page through header("Location:) breaks the link to the page. At this point I am passing three parameters and that breaks the link. If I only pass one of those parameters, the link works fine. I should also note that the url that is shown in the browser URL field is correct but it just says the page cannot be found. I am using WordPress.

So the code I have is:

```
if(isset($_GET['user_email']) && isset($_GET['name'])){

    $email = $_GET['user_email'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];

  //authenticate the request and send the data to DB or write to text file   
 }
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wpeu_users WHERE user_email = '$email'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
  //return $result;

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    // The query returned 0 rows!
    echo "That email address is not in the database.";
    $id = "no";
    header("Location: https://somesite.ca?id=no#info");
    exit();  
 } else { 
    echo "that email address is in the database";
    $id="yes";
    $url_param = "id=$id&name=$name&email=$email";

   header("Location: https://somesite.ca/welcome-back?$url_param");
   exit();
  }

 $conn->close();

 ?>
```

This ends up passing the following url to the destination page: https://somesite.ca/somepage?id=yes&name=somename&email=someemail

Using this url, WordPress complains that the page cannot be found. If I remove any two of those parameters, the page is found fine. What am I missing here?

Dave

Answer (score 0):

So, as it turns out, this is all because I used the term name as a parameter and that is a WordPress reserved term so you cannot use it in a url to a page hosted on Wordpress. Who knew? (Well I suppose lots of people ... but apparently not me :-))